# Jenkins UI stopped working after a reboot

Tags: java, jenkins, ubuntu-14.04

I ran into this problem suddenly, and the help provided on jenkins is not solving my issue. I didnt do plugin update, i just did a reboot, after deleting the ssh key, and the jenkins UI stopped working, it shows no error, except for the

> This site can’t be reached

I tried reading the following some of the suggestions online to check the deadlock. but, i'm getting error, inspite of using sudo

```
sudo jmap -heap 1171

 Attaching to process ID 1171, please wait...
 Error attaching to process: Doesn't appear to be a HotSpot VM (could not 
 find symbol "gHotSpotVMTypes" in remote process)
 sun.jvm.hotspot.debugger.DebuggerException: Doesn't appear to be a HotSpot 
 VM (could not find symbol "gHotSpotVMTypes" in remote process)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.HotSpotAgent.setupVM(HotSpotAgent.java:412)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.HotSpotAgent.go(HotSpotAgent.java:305)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.HotSpotAgent.attach(HotSpotAgent.java:140)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.Tool.start(Tool.java:185)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.Tool.execute(Tool.java:118)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.HeapSummary.main(HeapSummary.java:49)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.tools.jmap.JMap.runTool(JMap.java:201)
    at sun.tools.jmap.JMap.main(JMap.java:130)
```

Comment: `Doesn't appear to be a HotSpot VM (could not 
 find symbol "gHotSpotVMTypes" in remote process)`

Comment: @RobertHarvey do you know, how to fix it?